# Tag about first-order logic

Tags: feature-request, tagging

Why we have two different tags ? :

- first-order logic

and

- predicate logic

Why not link them via synonimy ?

Thanks

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8267/predicate-logic-the-best-tag

Comment: And also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/10971#10971